# Size forms for various sizes of suits Monitors

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a desktop app Windows Forms

I'm working on a `19`' but what if I install the app where you have a monitor less measured as `14`' or less maybe.

What I'm doing is creating my main form with `1024` x `768` but as to create my other forms is necessary to lower my screen resolution to `1024` x `768`?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your code to see where you adapt to different screens?

Comment: I do not have a code to do that rather I am investigating how I can fix it. 
Since there are people who already go through this.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the monitor size, everything to do with its *resolution*.  Creating a 1024 x 768 form is pretty safe (don't forget about the task bar), you can put that in your prerequisites pretty easily.  Keep in mind that going up is always easy, going down never is.  I don't otherwise see a problem statement in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to manipulate your forms size depending on the size of the screen, then I recommend using Screen.GetWorkingArea(), but just to add on to @jaredbaszler. This is what the documentation states about GetWorkingArea:

Retrieves the working area for the display that contains the largest region of the specified control. The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars.

It will only provide the screen height and width values as if nothing was within the screen. I would say that the working area would be your best option though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you can do and thankfully Windows forms will take care of most of it for you.  If you enable scroll bars on your forms then any controls that aren't visible on a small screen will activate the scroll bars so your user can get to them.

Also - Flow Layout Panels are helpful as they will automatically position your controls for you based on how much available screen space there is.  You have to set the maximum bounds of the flow layout panel though which leads me to my next point.

You have to get into using the System.Windows.Forms.Screen namespace to help size your forms (if you are going the full screen route).  Specifically the GetWorkingArea() method.  That method gives you the available working space of whatever monitor/resolution you are working in - even accounting for the windows taskbar.

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.